# openldap set single user password to never expire

Tags: openldap

is it possible to use ldapmodify to set a single users password to never expire?
for example I have a system user that causes the system to fail if the password expires so I need to make it never expire while all the other user password do expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is what I did created a second password policy and then modified the Manager user to use the new policy rather than the default policy. see http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. usually. Depends on the system, the OS, etc (usually it's something like putting the `pwdMaxAge` value to `0` so it never expires . But this if for OpenLDAP itself, it's not necessarilly the same attribute that your target system/OS uses for its own password expiration dates : maybe those are stored elsewhere in ldap for that system/OS...

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but that changes the global password max age not the max age for an individual user password. I need everyone to have a max age except for this one user.